# service register in consul,but it show is now critical

Tags: java, spring-cloud-consul

my project's configure is:
spring-cloud-dependencies is Dalston.RELEASE,
springboot is 1.5.8.RELEASE;
the dependencies like:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

the code like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}

@GetMapping("/test/getId")
public String getId(@RequestParam("id") String id){

    return "return the id is:"+id;
}
}
```

consul is running(consul.exe agent -dev),when running the project, the consul show the log:

```
    2018/08/09 15:49:59 [WARN] agent: Check "service:mdp-service-release-flatform-provider-cache-redis-dev-dev-9098" is now critical
```

I cannot consume the provider, what is wrong?

Comment: the consul is single